# Purification of polar NHS esters

Tags: chromatography, purification, esters

What are the options that I might be missing for the purification of a molecule with the following characteristic:

1. Contains an activated ester that reacts with water (NHS)
2. Reacts readily with alcohols
3. Does not elute on silica gel (typical or spherical) with THF, Acetone, EtOAc, DCM, or Acetonitrile
4. Is not a solid that can be precipitated, rather some horrible gum
5. Decomposes rapidly in prep-LC on C18 0.1% TFA (10% back to acid after 20min run in best cases) typical loss of material is about 50% from initial mass.
6. Greasiest solvent that solubilises is DCM

Impurities are mainly side product from NHS coupling reagents or relatively uncharacterized impurities with properties similar to final product.

Honestly, I have not much hope left to find something there but if you know of conditions what could provide separation in reverse phase HPLC with aprotic solvent, I'm all ears.

Edit: I'm open also to hear about volatile buffer system that could be in a pH range that would allow greater stability of the NHS in water.

Comment: How does it behave on alumina?

Comment: Haven't checked. I always thought it was rather similar to silica gel but really inconvenient. Would you expect a different result? The core structure look like silica gel a lot. I'll try to find tlc for that...

Comment: Alumina can give different results so it is worth checking. Do you have access to the range of 'flavoured' silicas?   Those can also give useful differentiation between substrates.

Comment: I can get pretty much anything, but I would like to get tlc before committing my product.

Comment: You can get tlc plates of the various favoured silicas

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll definitely order a couple of these, but again which solvent will be the key question. I've never been convinced that they effectively cap all the silanols on there... Sigh! Friday is time for a beer 

Comment: Try C18 prep LC but use a different buffer like ammonium formate at pH 4 or even, if you have to, ammonium bicarbonate at pH 6.5. If the compound is stable at this more neutral pH, it could be a way to go.

Comment: Crazier options might be to try DMSO in place of water for the "weak" C18 solvent.  Not sure if anyone is your lab would like you if you pumped liter quantities of DMSO through a prep LC column though.